# Nifi issue with running python script

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigdata, apache-nifi

My use case is : 
I have taxi data for years 2013-2019 and i want to fetch data for 2018 
from Bigquery to Google cloud storage and then to Amazon S3 bucket.

I have already written a python script and it is sucessfully transferring data to Google Cloud Storage bucket.

Also, i have made a nifi flow which is transferring the GCP Bucket data to Amazon S3 successfully.

Problem is that i am not able to make a flow in nifi that when my python script is executed successfully , the flow(which i have already made) is triggered.
Basically i am not able to connect (running my python script ) and (nifi flow).
I want to automate it.

Comment: What exactly your problem? Why you can't connect your python to next step?

Comment: If i use ''ExecuteScript'' Processor to run the python script then this processor doesnt connect to "ListGCSObject" processor because ListGCSObject doesn't need an input . LISTGCSObject is independent and it is already configured.
Hence ,i cant connect them both.
Should i use Apache Airflow instead?